# Calculate value in textbox and display result in corresponding label

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a list of textboxes with corresponding labels. When the user inputs a number in the textbox, the result is shown in its corresponding label on keyup. I can do this one by one but I would like to loop through the textboxes to show the result in the corresponding label and I'm not sure how to do that.

This is the code:

```
 <div id="p">
    FOO
    <input type="text" id="nop" />
</div>

 <div id="e_table">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th><h3>ABC</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>PQR</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>XYS</h3></th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Staff</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="as" /></td>
                        <td><label id="las">label</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Office</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="bo"/></td>
                        <td><label id="lbo">label</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Administrative</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="mca" /></td>
                        <td><label id="lmca">label</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function() {


         $("#as").keyup(function() {
        var nop = $("#nop").val();
        var val = $(this).val();
        var formula = parseInt(val/40/nop);
        $("#las").html(formula);
    });                                                             



});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach the `keyup` event to all `input:text` elements within the table rather than on each one individually. The only *smell* is how you select the corresponding `label` element.

```
$(function() {
    $("#e_table").delegate("input:text", "keyup", function() {
        var $input = $(this);
        var value = parseInt($input.val() / 40 / $("#nop").val());
        $input.closest("tr").find("label").html(value)
    });
});
```

Comment: You should combine all three var statements and also that is not very dynamic. Wrapping the input and it brakes, adding another td next to the inputs td will also brake it.

Comment: I took what the user had and pasted it to get it to work. I did not optimize it.
I just went on the OPs current layout to fit their need. Definitely not downvote worthy but whatever floats your boat.

Comment: well, the OP liked it since they marked it as the answer so I would say I did both.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code

```
$('#e_table').find('tr input').keyup(function () {
  var $this   = $(this),
      $label  = $(this).closest('tr').find('label'),
      nop     = $("#nop").val(),
      val     = $(this).val(),
      formula = parseInt(val/40/nop);

  $label.html(formula);
});
```

Comment: looping through each `tr` to attach a `keyup` event is probably the most inefficient way to do this.

Comment: maybe in a larger perspective

Comment: Ehm ok so you think you're good is better where the label _has_ to be in the absolute next td? And that the input cannot be wrapped since you're looking at the direct parent and assuming that the next element is the td containing the label? I'm really surprised you have that many reputation points.

Comment: What I did was give the person a simple solution based on the markup they already had. Sometimes you need to do that rather than refactor everything they've already done.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9230/discussion-between-hunter-and-tbleckert)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to all relevant inputs, see my example at http://jsfiddle.net/r3XGb/5/

Note:

- I changed your jQuery to match all inputs with class "calc" (behaviour one-by-one).
- keyup event added to #nop with looping through all inputs above (using class selector, THIS is actually the answer to your question, I guess).
- Putting all logic into a function.
- Calling that function upon document.ready (with pre-populated inputs).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following:

```
// this is just to generate the 'for' attribute so that clicking the label focuses the field
$('td label').each(
    function(){
        $(this).attr('for',this.id.substring(1));
    });

$('input:text').keyup(
    function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (!isNaN(val)){
            $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]')
                .text(val);
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7YMKY/1/).

References:

- [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).
- [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).
- [`:text` input selector](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/).
- [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).